# How can solve this issue while facing during duilding the docker file?

Tags: docker, devops

I am trying to build my docker container but it is showing this issue.

```
abdullahshahid@fedora:~/Documents/hello$ docker build -t hello .
ERROR: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
abdullahshahid@fedora:~/Documents/hello$
```

Yesterday, the image file was creating while today while I have started working on the project again and it is showing this error.

Comment: add more details

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Have you tried to run your command with sudo ? `sudo docker builder -t hello`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether your docker demon is running or not?
Use the below command to check:

```
systemctl status docker
```

If it's not running then start it using the below command:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Answer (score 0):

If the docker daemon is running, check your user is in `docker`  group and if it's not

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```